# HTML being encoded automatically

Tags: asp.net, html, encoding

I have a .htm file with some template stuff that looks a little like this:

```
<div>
 <h1>My template</h1>
 <div>
   <%replacable%>
 </div>
</div>
```

I get my helper to read it in:

```
string str = Helper.ReadFile("~/Templates/myTemplate.htm");
```

I replace my stuff:

```
str = str.Replace("<%replacable%>", "tadah!");
```

I set my editor:

```
AjaxHTMLEditor.Content = str;
```

by the time it gets to the editor it's all bloody crap :(

```
%Address1%&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;%Address2%&gt;, &lt;%Address3%&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;%Postcode%&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
```

and here's my readfile code:

```
public static string ReadFile(string filename)
{

    string contents = "";

    filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename);

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        sr = File.OpenText(filename);

        contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return contents;
}
```

Why is my HTML being encoded????

if I set the AjaxHTMLEditor with a direct string then it's fine:

```
AjaxHTMLEditor.Content = "<div> <h1>My template</h1> <div>   tadah! </div> </div>";
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the text in template file itself is not encoded? Open it up in notepad and check.

Comment: Yeah, already tried to open it in notepad HTML comes out as it should and NOT encoded. Thanks for the attempt :)

Answer (score 4):

> I replace my stuff:

```
str.Replace("<%replacable%>", "tadah!");
```

You are not replacing anything here. You don't return a value. In .NET strings are immutable so the `.Replace` method returns the new value.

If you wanted to replace you would do:

```
var filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates/myTemplate.htm");
string str = File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("<%replacable%>", "tadah!");
```

At this stage the `str` variable will contain unencoded value.

What happens next will greatly depend on what you are doing with this `str` variable. For example if `AjaxEditor.Content` already HTML encodes the value (whatever this `AjaxEditor` is) this is probably the reason why you get HTML encoded at the end.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I've fixed the .replace problem (total noob error on my part). I'm using the Ajax HTML Editor and it shouldn't be encoding it as far as I'm aware, the problem lies somewhere else :(